# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen dia, estoy practicando programacion web con PHP y MySQL.
En este caso inteno de hacer una App que muestre listas de tareas junto a sus tareas correspondientes en una misma pagina.

Tengo el listado de las listas de tareas bien, para mostrar las tareas de las listas uso el siguiete codigo:

```
<?php
 //Obtenemos todas las listas
 $resultado = $lista -> read();
 //Iniciamos un foreach para imprimir las listas en cards diferentes
 foreach($resultado as $lista):
?>
    ...
    .
    Codigo HTML donde se imprimen los datos de las listas
    .
    ...
<?php
//Obtenemos todas las tareas
$resultado = $tarea -> readOne($lista["id_lista"]);
//Iniciamos un foreach para imprimir todas las tareas en la lista correspondiente
foreach($resultado as $tarea):
?>
```

Al momento de obtener las tareas la primera ida de mi foreach me obtiene las tareas de mi primera lista pero al momento de querer obtener las tareas de la segunda lista de tareas me marca el error :**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function readOne() on array**
En esta instruccion para especificar `$resultado = $tarea -> readOne($lista["id_lista"]);`

Uso PDO para la obtencion de los datos de la base de datos, a continuacion muestro las clases correspondientes

**tareas class**

```
<?php 
    include_once("conexion.class.php");

    class Tareas extends Conexion{

        //Funcion para leer tareas de una lista
        public function readOne($id_lista){

            $consulta = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT id_lista, t.tarea, t.check_tarea, t.id_tarea FROM tarea t 
            left join lista USING (id_lista) 
            WHERE id_lista=:id_lista 
            ORDER by t.tarea ASC");

            $consulta -> bindParam(':id_lista', $id_lista, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $consulta -> execute();
            $resultado = $consulta -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $resultado;
        }
    }
    
    //Se crea el objeto de la clase y se llama a la conexion
    $tarea = new Tareas;
    $tarea -> conexion();
?>
```

**listas class**

```
<?php 
    include_once("conexion.class.php");

    class Listas extends Conexion{

        //Funcion para mostrar todas las listas
        public function read(){

            $consulta = $this -> db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM lista 
            ORDER by nombre ASC");   
             
            $consulta -> execute();
            $resultado = $consulta -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $resultado;
        }

    }

    //Se crea el objeto de la clase y se llama a la conexion
    $lista = new Listas;
    $lista -> conexion();
?>
```

**conexion class**

```
<?php

    class Conexion{
        var $db = null; 

        //Funcion que realiza la conexion a la base de datos
        public function conexion(){
            $tipo = 'mysql';
            $host = 'localhost';
            $db_nombre = 'mibasededatos';
            $usuario = 'miusuario';
            $contrasena = 'contrasenafake';

            $conexion = $tipo.':dbname='.$db_nombre.';host='.$host;
            $this -> db = new PDO($conexion,$usuario,$contrasena);
        }
    }

    //Creacion de objeto de la conexion
    $conexion = new Conexion;
    $conexion -> conexion();
?>
```

Ya hay preguntas con este error pero no termine de comprender el error, alguien que me pueda aclarar mi duda?

Gracias, buen dia.

Comment: No veo el `require` en tu archivo donde llames la clase Listas.

Comment: Se me ocurre que en algún lado (quizas en la parte del html que no está en la pregunta) estas sobreescribiendo la variable `$tarea`